# No guarda mis productos almacenados al salir de la sesión

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, session

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación de ecommerce con laravel, tengo un detalle con mi carrito de compras, al salir de la sesión y al volver a entrar no guarda lo que ya tenía. Me han comentado que es necesario mandar de alguna manera los productos a una base de datos, pero desconozco como. Hice uso de variables de sesión para hacer la funcionalidad.

Controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Cart;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!\Session::has('cart')) \Session::put('cart', array());
    }

    //show cart
    public function show()
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $total = $this->total();
        return view('store.cart', compact('cart','total'));

    }

    //add item
    public function add(Product $product, Request $request)
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $product->quantity = 1;
        $cart[$product->slug] = $product;
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);


        return redirect()->route('home');
    }


    //delete item
    public function delete(Product $product)
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        unset($cart[$product->slug]);
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }

    //update item
    public function update(Product $product, $quantity)
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $cart[$product->slug]->quantity = $quantity;
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }

    //trash item
    public function trash()
    {
       \Session::forget('cart');

        return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }

    //total
    private function total()
    {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $total = 0;
        foreach($cart as $item){
            $total += $item->price * $item->quantity;
        }
        return $total;
    }

    // Detalle del pedido
    public function orderDetail()
    {
        if(count(\Session::get('cart')) <= 0) return redirect()->route('home');
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $total = $this->total();
        return view('store.order-detail', compact('cart', 'total'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Haz intentado usar el Cache?

Comment: Cómo haces el logout del usuario? puedes escribir el código?

Comment: @Dohko19 No, ¿cómo seria eso?

Comment: @Julio te adjunto el codigo

Comment: @if(Auth::check())
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{ Auth::user()->user }}<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="">Salir</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

else
   
endif

Comment: Gracias. Qué haces en la ruta `logout`?